# Row-level formula limitations when referencing other objects

Tags: reporting, report-formula

In my Activities report I have a simple row-level formula:

```
CASE(Activity.Account.Industry_Sector__c, "Construction", "1", CASE(Activity.Account.Industry_Sector__c, "Maritime", "2",  "Other"))
```

There are plenty of construction and maritime accounts in my report but the formula always returns "Other".

For test purposes, I created a similar formula for other field and it's working as expected:

```
CASE(Activity.Type__c, "Call", "1", CASE(Activity.Type__c, "Meeting", "2", "Other"))
```

I run a few more tests for other fields. As long as I'm referencing fields directly on the activity, the formula works perfectly fine but when the field is on a related object (e.g. account), it returns "Other".

After some research I haven't found any limitations to how far away the field I want to refer to can be.

Is anyone aware of such limitations or is there anything wrong with my formula?

Comment: What is the Account field on the Activity object, is it an Id or a lookup/master detail?

Comment: The Account field (a picklist, not multi-select though) was added to the custom Activity report type as a lookup.
The field is not added to the Activity object in any way.

Answer (score 0):

I successfully had a row level formula apply to lookup fields as follows

Report type: `Activities with Account`

Row level formula looked like this:

```
CASE(Account.Industry_Sector__c, 
     "Construction", "1", 
     "Maritime", "2",
     "Other")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I didn't want to make my question overcomplicated, but I have to check a few more picklist fields in my formula (not only Account Industry Sector) and then I have to repeat CASE every time which in the end breaks my formula.
In the end, I solved it with CASE and IF that is checking whether the first field is empty and putting whatever is in the second field,


`CASE(
IF(ISBLANK(TEXT(Activity.Account.Industry_Sector__c)), TEXT(Activity.Store_Outlet__c.Industry_Sector__c), TEXT(Activity.Account.Industry_Sector__c)),
"Construction","1",
"Maritime","2",
"Other")`

Comment: So, it sounds like you have a solution that works now? That row level formulas do work cross-object?